# The Spring.Net lost of the object

Tags: iis, web-config, spring.net

When I change web.config file on the live server(For test I changed ApplicationSettings and property of the Spring objects) Spring ceases injection one of the references.

ConifugurationErrorsException: Error creating context 'spring.root': Could not load type from string value 'Contracts.Account.Consumer.IConsumerAccountManager'.]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the assembly name to avoid surprises :
"'Contracts.Account.Consumer.IConsumerAccountManager, MYASSEMBLYNAME'

Comment: Thanks, I missed it. I am ashamed.

Comment: If you are using VS2010, you should try the VS Extension to avoid this kind of errors :
http://springframework.net/#spring-vsnet-addin-1.0.0-released